# C++ Passing function templates as arguments to other functions as callback

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

I have a function like below:

```
template<typename... Args>
int
error_handler (const char *format, Args&... args)
{
    // deal with the information passed
}
```

I am writing a library that takes such a function pointer during init time, so the library can invoke this as a callback when something happens. However, I am not able to write such an API. I attempted the following but the compiler doesn't like it:

```
void init(template<typename... Args> int (*error_handler_cb)(const char *format, Args&... args));
```

Here is the error:

```
error: expected identifier before 'template'
     void init(template<typename... Args> int (*error_logger_cb)(const char *format, Args&... args),
                      ^~~~~~~~
libapi.hpp:20:22: error: expected ',' or '...' before 'template'
```

Can someone please help me to overcome this ?

Comment: Templates are an illusion. A mirage. They don't exist until they're actually instantiated. As such "passing function templates as arguments" makes no sense in C++. You can only pass concrete objects. A template isn't concrete until it is instantiated. The only situation where template can sort of be used like a parameter would be as a parameter to another template.

Comment: Use generic lambda: `auto error_handler = [](const char *format, auto&... args){ ... };` (C++14+) or simply write such functor manually: `struct error_handler{ template <typename... Args> int operator() (const char *format, Args&... args) { ... } };` (C++11+).

Answer (score 0):

You can't pass a type as a function parameter, only a value. You may leverage the constraint on `init` by just requiring a functor:

```
template<typename F>
void init(F f)
{
    // ...
}
```

If you need to store `f` to call it later, [`std::function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) may be an option:

```
namespace {
    std::vector<std::function<int(void)>> init_functions;
}

template<typename F>
void init(F f)
{
    init_functions.push_back(f);
}
```

A complete implementation may looks like this:

```
namespace {
    std::vector<std::function<int(void)>> init_functions;
}

template<typename... Args>
int
error_handler (const char *format, Args&&... args)
{
    do_something(format);
    do_something(args...);

    return 0;
}

template<typename F>
void init(F f)
{
    init_functions.push_back(f);
}

int main()
{
    auto f = []() {
        return error_handler("test", 4, 2);
    };
    init(f);
    return init_functions[0]();
}
```

Note the use of rvalue reference in `error_handler` instead of lvalue reference as you did. This allows to pass rvalues in the `main` function.

See a [live example](http://rextester.com/RGQO84555) on rextester.